# How to implement glob ** for an object?

Tags: javascript, search, recursion, glob

How can I support a globstar-style `**` search through a JavaScript object?

This is just like lodash's [`_.get`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.2#get) except that the object to query can contain these special `*` and `**` properties which will be matched against if there is no exact match.

In the example code below, the `{ **: { middleName: 3 }}` rule should match the following paths:

```
['middleName']
['clients', 'middleName']
['clients', '0', 'middleName']
```

Because `**` matches 0 or more elements, so `{**: { middleName: x }}` essentially matches any array ending with `'middleName'` and returns `x`.

However, since there's *also* a `*` rule, which only matches a single level (exactly 1 element having any value), that should take precedence over the `**`, causing the second path to evaluate to `{ lastName: 2 }` instead.

In practice, I don't care too much about precedence because one shouldn't be writing overlapping "rules", but I can't figure out how to implement `**` regardless.

If you need a more practical example, what I intend to use this for is: the 1,2,3 numbers will be replaced with validator functions, and the "paths" will be `<input>` names. In this way I can specify validation rules for my form.

Also, I only really want to return leaf nodes, so the fact that one of them returns `{ lastName: 2 }` is kind of weird, but it's an edge case I don't care much about. If `**` took precedence over this because it's a leaf-node-match, I suppose that would be even better.

**Code:**

```js
function glob(object, path, defaultValue) {
  let [first, ...rest] = path;
  let value = object[first];
  if (value === undefined) {
    value = object['*'];
    if (value === undefined) {
      // TODO: support **
      return defaultValue;
    }
  }
  if (rest.length) {
    return glob(value, rest, defaultValue);
  }
  return value;
}

let rules = {
  firstName: 1, // matches ['firstName']
  clients: {
    '*': {
      lastName: 2, // matches ['clients', anything, 'lastName']
    }
  },
  '**': {
    middleName: 3, // matches [...anything, 'middleName']
  }
}

console.log(glob(rules, ['firstName'])); // 1
console.log(glob(rules, ['clients', '0', 'lastName'])); // 2
console.log(glob(rules, ['clients', '0', 'middleName'])); // should be 3
console.log(glob(rules, ['clients', 'middleName'])); // should be { lastName: 2 } or 3, whatever's easier to implement
console.log(glob(rules, ['middleName'])); // should be 3
```

Comment: "How can I support a globstar-style ** search through a JavaScript object?" aren't you searching through arrays of string (which you refer "paths")? Problem statement could be  less confusing.

Comment: @spinkus Yeah, I know it's a little confusing, that's why I included examples. I'm not searching through the arrays/paths though -- the path is used as a key into the object. This is just like lodash's [_.get](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.2#get) except the object can contain these special `*` and `**` keys.

Answer (score 3):

Problems seems a lot like file path globbing. The rules object in your code seems a bit strange. Not sure how you ended up with it or what its wider purpose might be but ... I think you can refactor your rules from an object into be glob paths. There are plenty of JS packages around for globbing. Following is a refactor using [minimatch](https://github.com/isaacs/minimatch) globber (added a rule to original list to show how you can reduce redundancy with glob expressions).

```
var minimatch = require("minimatch")
var _ = require('underscore')

rules = {
  'firstName': 1,
  'clients/*/lastName': 2,
  '**/middleName': 3,
  'people/*/+(middleName|lastName)': 4,
}
rule_keys = _.keys(rules).sort().reverse() // Force a well defined match order.

function glob(rules, path) {
  path = path.join('/')
  for(r of rule_keys) {
    if(minimatch(path, r)) {
      return rules[r];
    }
  }
}

paths = [
  [['firstName'], "1"],
  [['clients', '0', 'lastName'], "2"],
  [['clients', '0', 'middleName'], "should be 3"],
  [['clients', 'middleName'], "should be 2|3"],
  [['middleName'], "should be 3"],
  [['people', '0', 'middleName'], "should be 4"],
];

for(p in paths) {
  console.log(glob(rules, paths[p][0]), paths[p][1]);
}
```

---

Indeed, minimatch implementation will likely interpret the string expressions into an object similar to the one you have shown - except more complex since it supports more features.

Comment: Yes, it is similar to file path globbing, that's why I referred to it as globbing :-) The rule format is just a nested version of what you've got there which will reduce redundancy a bit as I add a lot of rules, and I'm using `.`s as separators instead of `/`s because they aren't actually file paths, its an object path, and dots are more common in JS and other programming languages for that. I hadn't considered actually using minimatch -- I think I'd have to disable a bunch of options to get it to work the way I want, but it could work. Not a fan of having to change my syntax though.

Comment: @mpen "The rule format is ... will reduce redundancy a bit as I add a lot of rules". minimatch supports brace and "extglob" (like +(a|b)) expansions to reduce redundancy. These expansions could probably reduce redundancy better than with the object format no? Updated answer to show an example.

Comment: The properties values would likely be different though. Matching both with one rule is not ideal.

Comment: Ah, see your point. Not ideal, simple though :). Would be clarifying to add such a case to the example rules in the question.